# How to generate a genbank reference database using OBITools3?

Tags: python, genbank

I am working on a metabarcoding project and am reeeeeally new to the bioinformatics end of things.
I want to create a reference database in OBITools3 by doing an in-silico PCR on all vertebrate sequences in Genbank, using my primer set. The OBITools3 tutorial shows how to get EMBL data [https://git.metabarcoding.org/obitools/obitools3/-/wikis/Wolf-tutorial-with-the-OBITools3#7-taxonomic-assignment-of-the-sequences], but not Genbank data. I don't know what the Genbank URI is, and can't seem to find any info about this online.
Maybe this is something quite obvious, but I just don't have the experience in this field yet. Any help is much appreciated!

Help info from OBITools3 documentation:

```
obi build_ref_db -h
usage: obi build_ref_db [-h] [--skip <N>] [--only <N>]
                        [--taxonomy OBI:TAXOURI] [--no-create-dms]
                        [--no-progress-bar] [--threshold <THRESHOLD>]
                        INPUT OUTPUT

positional arguments:
  INPUT                 Data source URI
  OUTPUT                Data destination URI

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit

Restriction to a sub-part options:
  Allows to limit analysis to a sub-part of the input

  --skip <N>            skip the N first sequences
  --only <N>            treat only N sequences

Input format options for taxonomy:
  --taxonomy OBI:TAXOURI
                        Taxonomy URI

Output options for DMS data:
  --no-create-dms       Don't create an output DMS if it does not already
                        exist

Option to deactivate the display of the progress bar:
  --no-progress-bar     Do not display progress bar

obi build_ref_db specific options:
  --threshold <THRESHOLD>, -t <THRESHOLD>
                        Score threshold as a normalized identity, e.g. 0.95
                        for an identity of 95%. Default: 0.99.
```